# While loop with EOF is confusing me

Tags: c

I am very new to learning C so sorry if this question is super simple. Here is a program that I'm trying to write - the purpose of which is to take inputs until EOF is reached and then it outputs the largest value and the smallest value of all the values inputted.

The problem after compiling and running is this: after inputting the values I press the EOF shortcut CTRL+Z and then after I press this shortcut the values written at the end of the code (min and max) do not print. So I am confused - since I wrote the code so that when EOF is reached the largest value and the smallest value are outputted.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    // declare variables
    float input = 0;
    float max = 0;
    float min = 0;

    // take input and make it equal to return value
    int return_value = scanf("%f", &input);

    // while return_value does not equal EOF
    while (return_value != EOF) {
        // if input is larger than the max
        if (input > max) {
            // then the input becomes the max
            input = max;
        }
        // else if the input is less than the min
        else if (input < min) {
            // than the input becomes the min
            input = min;
        }

        int return_value = scanf("%f", &input);
    }

    // print the largest number
    printf("%.2f ", max);

    // print the smallest number
    printf("%.2f\n", min);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You are defining `return_value` twice. The inner one is seen only within the `while` block, but not in the condition. Remove the `int`.

Comment: Basically, `int return_value = scanf ( "%f", &input );` in the end of your program should be `return_value = scanf ( "%f", &input );`. I'd also recommend enabling warnings in your compiler (if you use gcc, my personal favorite combination of flags is `-Wall -Wextra -Wshadow -Werror`).

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Comment: Just a recommendation for this sort of problem. You might want to set min to 999999 or some large number. Unless you're having the user input negative numbers, your min will never be lower than 0. You can also set max to -9999 if you're accepting negatives. Hope this helps.

Comment: Virtual Machine with Ubuntu 17.10 Artful (64bit)

Comment: Then you should use `Ctrl-D`.

Comment: I was using the wrong shortcut It seems then...

Comment: You have code problem as well

Comment: Note that `scanf()` will return 0 if the input is not recognizable as a floating point number.  Your test against `EOF` is dangerous; you'll be spinning in a loop if there is bogus data (e.g. a letter) in the input.  Use `while ((return_value = scanf("%f", &input)) == 1)` to control the loop.  You may then decide you don't even need the `return_value` variable.  You should aim not to write the same `scanf()` statement twice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others have pointed out ...
You were re-defining `return_value`.

Nonetheless ...
I don't think using `EOF` is reliable. If you are willing to consider an alternative, you could try the following - which breaks the loop when the user types any non-digit character.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    // declare variables
    float input = 0;
    float max = 0;
    float min = 0;

    // take input and make it equal to return value
    int n_convs = scanf("%f", &input);

    // while return_value does not equal EOF
    while (n_convs > 0) {
        // if input is larger than the max
        if (input > max) {
            // then the input becomes the max
            max = input;
        }
        // else if the input is less than the min
        else if (input < min) {
            // than the input becomes the min
            min = input;
        }

        n_convs = scanf("%f", &input);
    }

    // print the largest number
    printf("%.2f ", max);

    // print the smallest number
    printf("%.2f\n", min);

    return 0;
}
```

Note also that the logic in your loop is somewhat faulty ...
It nees to be

```
if (input > max) {
    // then the input becomes the max
    max = input;
}
```

(not `input = max`).

Comment: *I don't think using EOF is reliable* - why is that? If it weren't reliable we could not process files/inputs with *arbitrary* characters in it.

Comment: `return_value > 0` is a superior test to `return_value != EOF` when the return is 0.

Comment: `float max = 0;
    float min = 0;` --> `float max = -FLT_MAX;  float min = FLT_MAX;` would make more sense.

Comment: @EugeneSh.: I retract my statement. Furthermore: since 1) you had already pointed out the vital problem in your comment and 2) the question was specifically about handling EOF - I will probably remove my answer shortly (since it doesn't really add much - even though there are other problems in the OP's code).

Comment: I still ended up using the EOF version but the problems were that I was using the wrong shortcut, setting input = max/min instead of max/min = input, redefining the return_value again in the while loop, and I set the min max variables to the wrong numbers where they should be a very small number for max and a very large number for the min. Multiple comments and answers helped me solve this problem.

Comment: @zaack7: Glad you got it sorted.